# Azure SIEM Data format from Syslog

Tags: azure, syslog, azure-sentinel

I am a novice in Azure and have been working on Logging and Analytics portion using Azure Monitor and AZ Sentinel.
I have Audit logs flowing from a third party vendor security appliance hosted in AZ VM to Syslog VM. The format of the data is in XML.

Syslog VM is connected as the Data Source connector to Sentinel SIEM.
I see that data is flowing into SIEM.

But how do I do data conversion?

Whether SIEM can understand xml?

Thanks in advance

Arul

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using LogStash to send the data into Sentinel instead.  It can handle conversions before pushing the data into Sentinel.